# Plotting multiple y-values versus x using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot `y1,y2,y3` all as a function of `x` and show all the three on a single plot. But it is showing only two plots. I present the current output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(-1,0,10)
print(x)
y1=36.554+5.418*np.exp(-1.327*x) 
y2=23.816+18.088*np.exp(-0.812*x)
y3=20.562+21.389*np.exp(-0.765*x)
print(y1,y2,y3)
plt.plot(x,y1,y2,y3)
```

The current output is

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqng1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plt.plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3)
```